# Sticky drop menu not sticking?

Tags: php, forms, drop-down-menu, sticky

I am making a contact page for a site and have all of the form fields sticking with the exception of the drop menu? I have done the code as good as I know how to but am very new to PHP and just have no idea where the problem is? Code is as follows:

```
   <?php
   $WebSearch = $SocialMedia =  $WordOfMouth = $Other ="";

if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST")
{

//Question
   if (empty($_POST["question"]))
   {$comment = "";}
   else
   {$comment = test_input($_POST["question"]);}

//WebSearch
   if (empty($_POST["WebSearch"]))
   {$comment = "";}
   else
   {$comment = test_input($_POST["WebSearch"]);}

//SocialMedia
   if (empty($_POST["SocialMedia"]))
   {$comment = "";}
   else
   {$comment = test_input($_POST["SocialMedia"]);}

//WordOfMouth
   if (empty($_POST["WordOfMouth"]))
   {$comment = "";}
   else
   {$comment = test_input($_POST["WordOfMouth"]);}

//Other
   if (empty($_POST["Other"]))
   {$comment = "";}
   else
   {$comment = test_input($_POST["Other"]);}

}
function test_input($data)
{
     $data = trim($data);
     $data = stripslashes($data);
     $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
     return $data;
}
?>

<form method="post" id="form" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
    <p id="info-req">How did you find about This site?</p>
    <!--Question--><select id="marketing" name="question">
        <option value="----------" style="color:black">----------</option>
        <option value="Web Search" style="color:black" name="WebSearch">Google Search</option><?php if(isset($_POST['WebSearch'])) {echo $_POST['WebSearch']; } ?>
        <option value="Social Media" style="color:black" name="SocialMedia">Social Media</option><?php if(isset($_POST['SocialMedia'])) {echo $_POST['SocialMedia']; } ?>
        <option value="Word of mouth" style="color:black"name="WordOfMouth">Word of mouth</option><?php if(isset($_POST['WordOfMouth'])) {echo $_POST['WordOfMouth']; } ?>
        <option value="Other" style="color:black" name="Other">Other</option><?php if(isset($_POST['Other'])) {echo $_POST['Other']; } ?>
    </select>

    <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Send" id="submit">
    </div>
</form>
```

I hope this is an easy fix or something I have missed? I am struggling with php after studying for a few months.

Thank you very much for any help,

Margate

Comment: You need to check which option needs to be selected then add the attribute `selected="selected"` to that `<option>` tag.

Comment: Umm...what do you mean by `form fields sticking with the exception of the drop menu`. Is this a design issue or do you have problems with some values not showing up?

Comment: I have other form fields on the page and everything is sticking when there is a form error. What is not sticking is the drop menu. I did not add the rest of the code into the code I posted above as it is working ok. All other entries are displaying the errors and sticking as they should be.

Comment: Can you point me in the right direction of how to check which option needs to be selected? I have added selected="selected" to the tag but do not fully understand how to check which option needs to be selected.     <option value="Other" style="color:black" name="Other" selected="selected">Other</option><?php if(isset($_POST['Other'])) {echo $_POST['Other']; } ?>

Answer (score 0):

I'll go through line by line to see what I find. Don't think of me as being picky. :-) Humm, let's see. I'll start with the form. I'm looking at everything. Hopefully, we can find a way to solve this error and minimize errors in the future. :-)
I am happy to help.

```
<form method="post" id="form" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
```

#1. Yes, you are trying to be safe, but if htmlspecialchars(), why not htmlentities()? Just say'in.

[PHP Manual: htmlentities()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)

```
<p id="info-req">How did you find about This site?</p>
```

#2. Learn about the `<label></label>` HTML tag and use that to label your form controls.

[W3C HTML 4.01: The label element.](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.9.1)

(The following is actually one line, but I'm breaking it into to a few items.)

```
<option value="Web Search" style="color:black" name="WebSearch">Google Search</option>
```

#3. Just a coding style issue, but you might want to put the `value=""` closer to the closing '>' in your opening `<option>` tag. Example...

```
<option value="Web Search">Google Search</option>
```

Notice I removed `style="color:black"` because you will be better served in the future if you put this style in an external style sheet as a class. Note: the color of the options's text is black by default in most user agents / browsers. Example.

```
.optionTextColor{color:black;}
```

Then your options would not have any CSS embedded in them. Naturally, if you do this ...

```
option{color:black;}
```

...all option elements on your page will inherit the styles you want them to have *without* a need for the `class=""` attribute.

```
<option class="optionTextColor" value="Web Search">Google Search</option> //using a specific class

<option value="Web Search">Google Search</option>                         //using a global, element level selector.
```

Also, notice that the the name attribute is gone because that is not a valid attribute of an `<option>` tag.

[W3C HTML 4.01: The Option Element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#h-17.6)

Search the page for *OPTION Attribute definitions*.

Here you will discover the **selected=""** attribute of the `<option>` tag, which is what you need to make
an `<option>` in a `<select>` control sticky. You'll need a PHP conditional statement, based on the value of `$_POST['question']` to print `selected="selected"` as an attribute of the `<option>` that you want to be sticky.

Work on these things first. There's lots of PHP things that could be discussed, but, as you said, you are in a learning phase. Cool.

Comment: I do not know why the numbered items got so big. It was not intentional.